# How do you run iex from Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elixir

I keep on getting this warning when I run iex using elixir-mode-iex from Emacs:

```
Warning: could not run smart terminal, falling back to dumb one
```

I think that this just means that I don't get tab completion, which I'm fine with. But I'd like a smart terminal if it's possible with elixir-mode in Emacs.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow; the tag Elixir is used for the functional meta-programming aware language built on top of the Erlang VM... you can hover on the tag to get a description.

Comment: @Ben That's what I was asking about. iex is the repl for Elixir. I was asking about the correct way to connect to that in Emacs.

Comment: What OS are you using, and can you run iex outside of emacs without the same warning?

Comment: @ChrisKeele I'm on OSX and it works perfectly from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elixir-mode-iex` uses the `comint-mode` major mode to interactive with `iex`. That also means that it's acting just like a dumb terminal (doesn't have the ability to process special escape sequences etc see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Dumb_terminals)).

As a workaround you just could use `term` which sends any key press directly to the subprocess itself. You could write a function like the following:

```
(defun my-elixir-iex ()
  (interactive)
  (term "iex"))
```

I'm working on an `iex` [Alchemist.el](https://github.com/tonini/alchemist.el) integration, which brings functionality like `Inf-Ruby` has. But until it's done try to just use `iex` via `term`

Cheers

Samuel

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that warning occurs when IEX can't find tty support. You can enable tty mode in emacs by invoking it with `-nw`.

Comment: Not making any difference for me using OSX, iex and iTerm.