# Elixir on Emacs: exec erl not found

Tags: macos, emacs, elixir

I am new to elixir on emacs. What does the elixir-mode-iex do? Is it similar to having a REPL? I have created a elixir file and when I run elixir-mode-iex from it, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/elixir/1.0.2/bin/elixir: line 100: exec: erl: not found

Process IEX exited abnormally with code 127
```

In my Emacs configuration, I have set:

```
Elixir iex Command value to  /usr/local/bin/iex 
Elixir Compiler Command: /usr/local/bin/elixirc
Elixir Mode Command: /usr/local/bin/elixir
```

All of the above three configurations are in my Path. I installed elixir using homebrew on OS Yosemite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Emacs's `exec-path` and your `PATH` are likely not in sync. Installing [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) should solve your problem.

Comment: Funny, I've long had stuff in my .emacs that goes the other way -- I call it `set-env-in-subshells`

Answer (score 4):

> What does the elixir-mode-iex do?

Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/27375432/1000458

If you have any other questions to the elixir-mode or elixir and emacs, you can find me on the #elixir-lang IRC channel on Freenode. Or just open an issue on https://github.com/elixir-lang/emacs-elixir or https://github.com/tonini/alchemist.el

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with Spacemacs (it already has exec-path-from-shell installed)
I didn't do anything special on install but there was a problem in the way my spacemacs.env was setup.
checking the file (SPC f e E), my PATH variable was defined twice. I removed the wrong definition and everything worked well.
Hope this helps somebody else.